# Need Alternative for "body.scrollTop" for Nested DIV to Scroll to Top Within impress.js Slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, impress.js

I'm using the [impress.js](https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/) framework (which apparently sets strict mode) and get the below message in Google Chrome when trying to scroll a nested DIV to its topmost location:

> body.scrollTop is deprecated in strict mode. Please use 'documentElement.scrollTop' if in strict mode and 'body.scrollTop' only if in quirks mode.

So, the below will not work for me when I click my "Scroll Up" button in the hopes of resetting a nested DIV to its top:

```
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#panel-scroller').offset().top });
```

You can see it fail at my test site:

http://www.berklie.com/stack

Can anyone tell me an alternative piece of code which to use, so that I can scroll to the top of the DIV when I click my "Scroll Up" button?

Thank you  in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the deprecation warning does not break functionality for now.

at least not on the pages i am using it on.

the problem is that the $('html,body') elements you animate are at scrollTop 0 already.

try:
$('#tile-row-edit').animate({'scrollTop': 0});

this even works from the javascript console on your demo.

have fun

jascha

Comment: Thanks! On top of that, I apparently was also using the wrong DIV ID.